# Which countries apply "electronic ban"?

Tags: usa, uk, electronic-items, middle-east

Some time ago US and following that UK announced that tablets, laptops and similar electronic devices are forbidden in incoming flights from a vast array of countries as well.

So are there only two countries-USA and UK, or are there any other countries which decided to apply same regulation?

Comment: Australia has done additional screening at ports

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently only the **US and UK** have applied a ban on electronics in the cabin.

Australia has implemented additional screening at the origin airport.